# "Questo" preceduto dai due punti deve riferirsi al concetto espresso da tutto ciò che lo precede e non solo all'ultimo sintagma?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

Salve, ho avuto una discussione sulla correttezza dell'utilizzo dei due punti nel seguente periodo. In grassetto ho inteso evidenziare le parti che esprimono la logica dell'enunciato.

> [in riferimento a congelamento e surgelazione] **La differenza** sostanziale tra le due modalità **è dunque rappresentata dalle temperature**, più alte nel congelamento rispetto a quelle della surgelazione, **e dal tempo** utilizzato per raggiungerle**: questo favorisce la formazione di macro-cristalli** di ghiacci nei loro tessuti che, per la loro dimensione, provocano una lacerazione delle membrane delle cellule vegetali e animali, consentendo dunque un periodo di conservazione minore per gli alimenti congelati rispetto a quelli surgelati.

Io ritengo che la funzione grammeticale di *questo* sia inequivocabile: esso si riferisce al sostantivo *tempo*. Non potrebbe altrimenti, credo, in quanto, tra gli unici due sostantivi che lo precedono, solo *tempo* e *congelamento* concordano con esso per genere e numero, e il secondo è non papabile, in quanto "isolato" in un inciso da due virgole.

D'altra parte, i due punti possono essere sostituiti da un'opportuna congiunzione, in questo caso *che*, la quale, pur appesantendo la lettura, a mio parere, evidenzierebbe che effettivamente *questo* si riferisce a *tempo*.

Aggiungo che percepirei lo stesso significato anche se i due punti fossero sostituiti da un punto fermo, benché, francamente, credo che i due punti mi aiutino a capire che *questo* si riferisce all'ultimo sintagma "tempo utilizzato per raggiungerle", ove mai decidessi che quanto scritto nel precedente capoverso non mi basta.

Il commento che fa da controaltare alla mio è che *questo*, **dopo i due punti**, si deve necessariamente riferire al "concetto" che è espresso da ***tutto*** ciò che precede i due punti (fino all'inizo del periodo, naturalmente). Nell'esempio di cui sopra, *questo* si riferirebbe perciò al ***fatto*** che la differenza […] sia rappresentata dalla temperatura e dal tempo […], per cui il periodo originario potrebbe essere reso così:

> **Il fatto che la differenza** sostanziale tra le due modalità **sia dunque rappresentata dalle temperature**, più alte nel congelamento rispetto a quelle della surgelazione, **e dal tempo** utilizzato per raggiungerle **favorisce la formazione** di macro-cristalli di ghiacci nei loro tessuti che, per la loro dimensione, provocano una lacerazione delle membrane delle cellule vegetali e animali, consentendo dunque un periodo di conservazione minore per gli alimenti congelati rispetto a quelli surgelati.

In relazione a questa riscrittura, io ritengo che la struttura logica della frase, *Il fatto che A sia rappresentato da B e C favorisce D*, cozzi con la realtà dei fatti, nella quale è *C* (il *tempo*), e non *il fatto che […]*, a favorire *D*.

Un riferimento ad una buna grammatica sarebbe ottimo.

Comment: In ogni caso rimane ambiguo. Dovrebbe d’essere sostituito da “*quest’ultimo”* se si vuole far riferimento all’ultimo concetto espresso o da “*tutto questo”* se si vuole far riferimento a tutto quanto detto prima.

Comment: @Hachi, non basta assumere/richiedere che la frase abba un senso compiuto a disambiguare? Fosse senza senso in entrambi i casi direi che è irrimediabilmente ambigua, ma se in uno dei due casi è senza senso e nell'altro no, mi sembra che sia facile dire che non è ambigua. Voglio dire, in _A è arrivato B_ è ambiguo quale sia il soggetto e quale il complemento, ma ciò diventa chiaro in _a casa è arrivato Paolo_ e _Paolo è arrivato a casa_.

Comment: Concordo con @Hachi che è una formulazione non limpidissima. Lo è in assoluto, e più ancora non sapendo come verrà letto il testo (di corsa, distrattamente, saltando qua e là). Certo, ragionandoci su si capisce, ma personalmente lo riformulerei in maniera che sia immediatamente chiara. A maggior ragione visto che è un testo tecnico, non mi sembrerebbe un peccato mortale neppure ripetere esplicitamente il soggetto (oppure usare una delle varie altre possibili formulazioni).

Comment: Concordo con il fatto che "questo" si riferisca al tempo (anche perché è così che funziona: un tempo di raffreddamento più veloce favorisce la formazione di gcristalli più grandi e di forma irregolare, metre un raffreddamento più lento crea strutture cristalline più piccole ed uniformi. Però non avrei usato i due punti; secondo me, ci andrebbe un punto e virgola.